# Is there a way to ignore a called variable in a concatenated string?

Tags: python, string

I'm writing code that drafts an email to anywhere between 1 and 4 recipients. The recipients are pulled from an Excel workbook. So if there are only 3 recipients, the cell for Person4 will be blank. The trouble is, it doesn't seem very Pythonic to write code for a separate email for each time there is a different number of recipients. I'd like to write one block of code for one email, and ignore a called variable if it's None

```
# collect recipent names from workbook
Person1 = sheet['BG1'].value
Person2 = sheet['BH1'].value
Person3 = sheet['BI1'].value
Person4 = sheet['BJ1'].value

# draft email
if Person4 != None:
     print('Dear ' + Person1 + ', ' + Person2 + ', ' + Person3 + ', and ' + Person4 + ',\n' + 
     'The faculty members of ... *continued body of email*')

elif Person3 != None:
     print('Dear ' + Person1 + ', ' + Person2 + ', and ' + Person3 + ',\n' + 
     'The faculty members of ... *continued body of email*')

elif Person2 != None:
     print('Dear ' + Person1 + ', and ' + Person2 + ',\n' + 
     'The faculty members of ... *continued body of email*')

else:
     print('Dear ' + Person1 + ',\n' + 
     'The faculty members of ... *continued body of email*')
```

Is there smarter way to write this? Only one block of code for any number of recipients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat your names as an array:

```
names = ', '.join(people[:-1]) + ' and ' + people[-1] if len(people) > 1 else people[0]
print(f'Dear {names},\n')
```

To populate the `people` array, you could do

```
people = [person for person in (Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4) if person]
```

There’s probably also a way of doing this directly with the Excel sheet range without first assigning the people’s names to individual variables.

Comment: Close, this will write `and person` if there's just one person.

Comment: @Barmer Good point. There’s probably no good way of using general code for that.

Comment: Yeah. If you have to do it a lot you can write a function for it.

Comment: To avoid assigning the `Person` variables: `people = [sheet[col+'1'].value for col in ['BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ']]`